# Alignment of groupplots with external graphics

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, horizontal-alignment, groupplots

Due to computational limitations, I'm creating a heatmap with another plotting software and importing the heatmap and colorbar using the `graphics` option and a `groupplot`. Additionally, I need to plot a second `yaxis` on top of the image to get meaningfull ticks.

The probelm is that, once I add the top line plot, the alignment breaks.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Bilder/}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread{
    T   x
    600.51  0.14
    595.42  1.04
    593.92  1.96
    587.42  2.95
    583.45  4.12
    579.92  4.6
    578.28  5.77
    569.69  7.00
    553.09  8.33
    539.71  9.24
    526.59  9.93
    522.43  10.95
    512.92  11.9
    486.56  13.06
    470.83  14.05
}\datah

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2, vertical sep=0pt}, height=0.5\textwidth]
        \nextgroupplot[
            scale only axis,
            enlarge x limits=false,
            width=0.5\textwidth,
            height=0.2\textwidth,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=14,
            xtick={0,2,...,14},
            ylabel={$T_{\mathrm{max}}$ in \si{\celsius}}
        ]
            \addplot table[x=x, y=T] {\datah};

        \nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]

        \nextgroupplot[
            scale only axis,
            enlargelimits=false,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            width=0.5\textwidth,
        ]
            \addplot graphics[xmin=0, xmax=1784, ymin=0, ymax=1676]{heatmap.png};
        
        \nextgroupplot[
            scale only axis,
            enlargelimits=false,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            width=0.05\textwidth
        ]
            \addplot graphics[xmin=0, xmax=98, ymin=0, ymax=1250]{colorbar.png};
    \end{groupplot}

    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2, vertical sep=0pt}, height=0.5\textwidth]
        \nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]

        \nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]

        \nextgroupplot[
            scale only axis,
            enlargelimits=false,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=14,
            xtick={0,2,...,14},
            xlabel={$x$ in \si{\mm}},
            ymin=0,
            ymax=700,
            y dir=reverse,
            ylabel={$t$ in \si{\second}},
            width=0.5\textwidth
        ]

        \nextgroupplot[
            scale only axis,
            enlargelimits=false,
            width=0.05\textwidth,
            xtick=\empty,
            ymin=20,
            ymax=610,
            yticklabel pos=right,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=1,
            title={$T$ in \si{\celsius}}
        ]
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Images:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add lo your question colorbar.png,, heatmap.png and the definition of `\datah`. It will be hard to help you without a minimum compilable code.

Comment: @SimonDispa that would be helpful, huh... I added both, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly your code, with some simplifications.

To fit the `.png`s, `headmap.png` was resampled to the same height as `colormap.png`.

[image: g2]

*Warning:* with this setting and using the environment  `groupplots`, the position of the colorbar will be modified if the top plot changes its height. See the update bellow.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Bilder/}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread{
    T   x
    600.51  0.14
    595.42  1.04
    593.92  1.96
    587.42  2.95
    583.45  4.12
    579.92  4.6
    578.28  5.77
    569.69  7.00
    553.09  8.33
    539.71  9.24
    526.59  9.93
    522.43  10.95
    512.92  11.9
    486.56  13.06
    470.83  14.05
}\datah

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2, vertical sep=1cm, horizontal sep=-1.5cm}, height=0.3\textheight, width=0.5\textwidth]
            \nextgroupplot[
            scale only axis,
            enlarge x limits=false,
            height=0.2\textheight,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=14,
            xtick={0,2,...,14},
            ylabel={$T_{\mathrm{max}}$ in \si{\celsius}}
            ]
            \addplot table[x=x, y=T] {\datah};
            \nextgroupplot[group/empty plot ]   
            \nextgroupplot[
            scale only axis,
            enlargelimits=false,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=14,
            xtick={0,2,...,14},
            xlabel={$x$ in \si{\mm}},
            ymin=0,
            ymax=750,
            y dir=reverse,
            ylabel={$t$ in \si{\second}},   
            ]
            \addplot graphics[xmin=0, xmax=14, ymin=0, ymax=750]{heatmap.png};
            \nextgroupplot[
            scale only axis,
            enlargelimits=false,
            width=0.05\textwidth,
            xtick=\empty,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=650,
            yticklabel pos=right,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=1,
            title={$T$ in \si{\celsius}}
            ]
            \addplot graphics[xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=650]{colorbar.png};          
        \end{groupplot}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** after follow-up question

The `groupplots` environment allows you to compare multiple plots that share the same
`[⟨options⟩]` as they apply to all plots in the entire environment, which saves a lot of typing.

In this case it is easier to just have the three graphs with the desired alignment with each other.

[image: d]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Bilder/}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread{
    T   x
    600.51  0.14
    595.42  1.04
    593.92  1.96
    587.42  2.95
    583.45  4.12
    579.92  4.6
    578.28  5.77
    569.69  7.00
    553.09  8.33
    539.71  9.24
    526.59  9.93
    522.43  10.95
    512.92  11.9
    486.56  13.06
    470.83  14.05
}\datah

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[name=plot1, scale only axis,
        enlarge x limits=false,
        height=0.15\textheight,
        width=0.4\textwidth,
        font=\small,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=15,
        xtick={0,2,...,14},
        ylabel={$T_{\mathrm{max}}$ in \si{\celsius}}]
        \addplot table[x=x, y=T] {\datah};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[name=plot2,at={($(plot1.south)-(0,1cm)$)},anchor=north, % adjust separation  <<<
        height=0.2\textheight,
        width=0.4\textwidth,
        scale only axis,
        enlargelimits=false,
        font=\small,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=15,
        xtick={0,2,...,14},
        xlabel={$x$ in \si{\mm}},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=750,   
        y dir=reverse,
        ylabel={$t$ in \si{\second}},
        ]
        \addplot graphics[xmin=0, xmax=15, ymin=0, ymax=750]{heatmap.png};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[name=plot3,at={($(plot2.east)+(0.25cm,0)$)},anchor=west, % adjust separation  <<<
        scale only axis,
        enlargelimits=false,
        height=0.2\textheight,
        width=0.02\textwidth,
        xtick=\empty,           
        font=\small,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=650,
        yticklabel pos=right,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=1,
        %title={$T$ in \si{\celsius}}, % optional
        ylabel near ticks, yticklabel pos=right,ylabel={$T$ in \si{\celsius}}
        ]
        \addplot graphics[xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=650]{colorbar.png};  
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, that is much simpler than before! However, there are still a few new issues I discovered: 1) Changing the height of the first plot shift the colorbar up and down as well. 2) The horizontal sep is too big, even when setting it to 0pt. 3) I want the axis to fit tight around the picture.

Comment: @fuj36840 Please see the updated answer.